# Check for None in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I would like to find where None is found in the dataframe.

```
pd.DataFrame([None,np.nan]).isnull()
OUT: 
      0
0  True
1  True
```

isnull() finds both numpy Nan and None values.

I only want the None values and not numpy Nan. Is there an easier way to do that without looping through the dataframe?

Edit:
After reading the comments, I realized that in my dataframe in my work also include strings, so the None were not coerced to numpy Nan. So the answer given by Pisdom works.

Comment: Afaik, this is not possible in Pandas: Pandas treats `None`s as missing data, and makes them (equivalent to) NaNs. Even by "looping through the dataframe", you won't be able to distinguish `None` from `NaN`. See the [documentation on missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html).

Comment: You may want to rethink your problem, and see if you *really* need to distinguish between NaN and `None`. Alternatively, you could introduce a (boolean) column indicating whether a value is `None` or a floating point value (including `NaN`); aka as a mask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `applymap` with a `lambda` to check if an `element is None` as follows, (constructed a different example, as in your original one, `None` is coerced to `np.nan` because the data type is `float`, you will need an `object` type column to hold `None` as is, or as commented by @Evert, `None` and `NaN` are indistinguishable in numeric type columns):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[None, 3], ["", np.nan]])

df
#      0      1
#0  None    3.0
#1          NaN

df.applymap(lambda x: x is None)

#       0       1
#0   True   False
#1  False   False
```

Comment: This *only* works because you are using an empty string, thus changing the dtype; change the string to any number (integer or float), and the `None` will change into a `NaN`.

Comment: @Evert Yes. I added the note that `None` can only exist in *object* type columns.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to get True/False for each line, you can use the following code. Here is an example as a result for the following DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[None, 3], ["", np.nan]])

df
#      0      1
#0  None    3.0
#1          NaN
```

### How to check `None`

#### Available: `.isnull()`

```py
>>> df[0].isnull()
0     True
1    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

#### Available: `.apply` `==` or `is` `None`

```py
>>> df[0].apply(lambda x: x == None)
0     True
1    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool

>>> df[0].apply(lambda x: x is None)
0     True
1    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

#### Available: `.values` `==` `None`

```py
>>> df[0].values == None
array([ True, False])
```

#### Unavailable: `is` or `==`

```py
>>> df[0] is None
False

>>> df[0] == None
0    False
1    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

#### Unavailable: `.values` `is` `None`

```py
>>> df[0].values is None
False
```

### How to check `np.nan`

#### Available: `.isnull()`

```py
>>> df[1].isnull()
0    False
1     True
Name: 1, dtype: bool
```

#### Available: `np.isnan`

```py
>>> np.isnan(df[1])
0    False
1     True
Name: 1, dtype: bool

>>> np.isnan(df[1].values)
array([False,  True])

>>> df[1].apply(lambda x: np.isnan(x))
0    False
1     True
Name: 1, dtype: bool
```

#### Unavailable: `is` or `==` `np.nan`

```py
>>> df[1] is np.nan
False

>>> df[1] == np.nan
0    False
1    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool

>>> df[1].values is np.nan
False

>>> df[1].values == np.nan
array([False, False])

>>> df[1].apply(lambda x: x is np.nan)
0    False
1    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool

>>> df[1].apply(lambda x: x == np.nan)
0    False
1    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

### Q: How check for `None` in DataFrame / Series

### A: `isna` works but also catches `nan`. Two suggestions:

1. Use `x.isna()` and replace none with nan
2. If you really care about `None`: `x.applymap(type) == type(None)`

<sub>I prefer comparing type since for example `nan == nan` is false.
In my case the `None`s appeared unintentionally so `x[x.isna()] = nan` solved the problem.</sub>

### Example:

`x = pd.DataFrame([12, False, 0, nan, None]).T`

```
x.isna()
      0      1      2     3     4
0  False  False  False  True  True
```

```
x.applymap(type) == type(None)
       0      1      2      3     4
0  False  False  False  False  True
```

```
x
    0      1  2    3     4
0  12  False  0  NaN  None

x[x.isna()] = nan
    0      1  2    3    4
0  12  False  0  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

To get a overall overview of non-null values you simpley use df.info()

[Dataframe ifo output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E2vM.png)