# turn none into empty list pandas

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, list, replace

```
import pandas as pd
Dates = [list(['None','11/04/1911', '03/06/1919']),
          list(['None']),
          list(['01/26/1912', '01/15/1918', '02/06/1917']),
          list(['None'])]
df= pd.DataFrame({'Text':['Hey 10.31.11  22|1|13 03-02-1919 d',
                              'things here 01-23-18 or 03-23-1984 then ',
                                  'stuff 1-22-12 01.11.18 or 2.2.17 so so ',
                          'nothing much'],
                          'ID': ['E1','E2', 'E3', 'E4'],
                  'Dates' : Dates,

                          })
```

which looks like

```
                             Dates         ID   Text
0   [None, 11/04/1911, 03/06/1919]          E1  Hey 10.31.11 22|1|13 03-02-1919 d
1   [None]                                  E2  things here 01-23-18 or 03-23-1984 then
2   [01/26/1912, 01/15/1918, 02/06/1917]    E3  stuff 1-22-12 01.11.18 or 2.2.17 so so
3   [None]                                  E4  nothing much
```

I have the following `df`. My goal is to replace the `['None']` e.g. row `1` and `3` to an empty list `[]` . My desired output is

```
         Dates   ID Text  New_Date
0                         [None, 11/04/1911, 03/06/1919]           
1                         []                                       
2                         [01/26/1912, 01/15/1918, 02/06/1917]  
3                         []
```

I have looked [Check for None in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271309/check-for-none-in-pandas-dataframe) and
[Python: most idiomatic way to convert None to empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034573/python-most-idiomatic-way-to-convert-none-to-empty-string) and [How to replace None only with empty string using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295740/how-to-replace-none-only-with-empty-string-using-pandas)

I have also tried

```
df['New_Date] = df['Dates].replace('None', list())
```

How do I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try code below, it first converts rows with list having only None to None string then replace it with empty list

```py
cond = df.Dates.str.join(",") == "None"
df.Dates.loc[cond] = [[] for _ in range(sum(cond))]
df
```

Comment: how would I create a new column with the code above? `df['New_Dates'].loc[cond] = [[] for _ in range(sum(cond))]` ?

Comment: you can make copy of Dates column ```df["new_dates"] = df.Dates.copy()``` then do the operation on new column

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) in pandas 0.25.1:

```
df['New_Date']=df['Dates'].explode().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x).split() if x.all() !='None' else [])
```

---

```
0          [None,11/04/1911,03/06/1919]
1                                    []
2    [01/26/1912,01/15/1918,02/06/1917]
3                                    []
Name: New_Date, dtype: object
```